# "Save Copy of Package as..." option missing

Tags: visual-studio-2005

In Visual Studio 2005 Professional, under Menu Bar "File", I do not have the option "Save Copy of Package AS..." which allows saving the package on the server.  How do I get this option to display and be useful?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean "Save Project as..."?

If so, yeah it's kind of a pain moving a VS project.  I usually just copy the directry tree using normal file copy commands, and fix up whatever problems crop up as a result manually.  Usually it's not bad - most of the project information deals with relative file locations pretty well.

Kinook Software has a utility that's supposed to help with this.  Try it if you think it has value:

- http://www.kinook.com/CopyWiz/

Answer (score 0):

You could activate it by customizing your menu.  See http://asqlb.blogspot.com/2010/12/save-copy-as-is-not-option-visual.html

If grayed out, drag the selected option to the file menu and drop it under "save as".